# C++11: Print `double` as hex?

Tags: c++, c++11, floating-point, ieee-754, gmp

I need to print a IEEE 64-bit `double` as hex string.

- I understand I have to use `std::hexfloat` in some way. But how to get the state of the stream right before that so it can be reset to the initial state?
- Must the precision also be hacked if the goal is to print with the highest possible precision? Or is that already a feature of hexfloat?
- The output must be in such a way that it can be used in a C/C++ source without any further ado, e.g. `-0x123.abc42p+10`.

The language I am using is C++11. Not more, not less.

Comment: _"...how to get the state of the stream right before that so it can be reset to the initial state..."_ see `std::ios_base::setf` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/setf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *But how to get
>   the state of the stream right before that so it can be reset to the
>   initial state?*

You can use the stream's [`flags()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/flags) function to retrieve and save the current settings, then later use the [`setf()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/setf) function to restore them, being sure to include `std::ios_base::floatfield` in the "mask" (second argument).

> *Must the precision also be hacked if the goal is to print with the
>   highest possible precision? Or is that already a feature of hexfloat?*

Yes. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed):

> Hexadecimal floating-point formatting ignores the stream precision
>   specification, as required by the specification of
>   std::num_put::do_put.

Here's a short demonstration program that may help:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using std::cout; using std::endl;

int main()
{
    double test = -0x123.abc42p+10;
    cout << std::fixed;         // Change from the default for demo
    cout << test << endl;       // Display in "Current" format
    auto fSave = cout.flags();  // Save current flags
    cout << std::hexfloat;      // Change to HEX float
    cout << test << endl;       // ... and display
    cout.setf(fSave, std::ios_base::floatfield); // Restore float field
    cout << test << endl;       // Restored to previous settings!
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The project where I need this uses actually a bit more than C++11, namely [GMP](https://gmplib.org) which supports print modifier `%a` from C99:

```cpp
// Include cstdarg / stdarg.h prior to gmp.h in the case
// we want va_list functions like gmp_vfprintf.
#include <cstdarg>
#include <gmp.h>

void func (double d)
{
    gmp_printf ("%a", d);
}

#include <iostream>

void func (std::ostream& ost, double d)
{
    auto len = gmp_snprintf (nullptr, 0, "%a", d);
    char str[1 + len];
    gmp_sprintf (str, "%a", d);
    ost << str;
}
```